# How can I prevent user to get outside certain coordinates in JSXGraph?

Tags: javascript, html, math, jsxgraph

Im trying to prevent the user to stay within (1000, 1000) and (-1000, -1000) area in JSXGraph.

Is it even possible ?

Comment: Do you want to restrict the reachable area when zooming and panning or when dragging elements?

Comment: Panning to be specific, for example, if the user moves with the arrows, downwards, it will stop it at -1000. Like a boundary basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite useful feature. I just added a new board attribute `maxBoundingBox` and it will be available in today's nightly build. Use it like this:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
    boundingbox: [-5,5,5,-5],
    maxboundingbox: [-8,8,8,-8],
    pan: {enabled: true},
    axis:true
});
```